# Filter not working on dataframe (dplyr) when using OR

Tags: r, dplyr

When I run this command:
 `filter(pitches, stand == "L", des == "Ball" | des == "Called Strike")`

It doesn't seem to work (note the stand column was not filtered), and I get this:

```
     num                   gameday_link stand b_height     px    pz  type           des
   (dbl)                          (chr) (chr)    (chr)  (dbl) (dbl) (chr)         (chr)
1     21 gid_2016_04_09_houmlb_milmlb_1     R     5-11  0.710 2.256     S Called Strike
2     37 gid_2016_04_09_houmlb_milmlb_1     R      6-4  0.819 3.336     S Called Strike
3     33 gid_2016_04_14_milmlb_slnmlb_1     L      6-3 -0.458 4.464     B          Ball
4     33 gid_2016_04_14_milmlb_slnmlb_1     L      6-3 -0.805 2.818     S Called Strike
5     17 gid_2016_04_19_milmlb_minmlb_1     L     5-10 -0.761 3.664     B          Ball
6     17 gid_2016_04_19_milmlb_minmlb_1     L     5-10 -0.574 3.472     B          Ball
7     17 gid_2016_04_19_milmlb_minmlb_1     L     5-10 -0.474 3.617     B          Ball
8     17 gid_2016_04_19_milmlb_minmlb_1     L     5-10 -0.350 1.267     B          Ball
9     50 gid_2016_04_19_milmlb_minmlb_1     L      6-0 -1.610 2.499     B          Ball
10    50 gid_2016_04_19_milmlb_minmlb_1     L      6-0 -1.177 1.543     B          Ball
```

When I run this command:
`filter(pitches, stand == "L", des == "Ball")`

It works, and I get this:

```
     num                   gameday_link stand b_height     px    pz  type   des
   (dbl)                          (chr) (chr)    (chr)  (dbl) (dbl) (chr) (chr)
1     33 gid_2016_04_14_milmlb_slnmlb_1     L      6-3 -0.458 4.464     B  Ball
2     17 gid_2016_04_19_milmlb_minmlb_1     L     5-10 -0.761 3.664     B  Ball
3     17 gid_2016_04_19_milmlb_minmlb_1     L     5-10 -0.574 3.472     B  Ball
4     17 gid_2016_04_19_milmlb_minmlb_1     L     5-10 -0.474 3.617     B  Ball
5     17 gid_2016_04_19_milmlb_minmlb_1     L     5-10 -0.350 1.267     B  Ball
6     50 gid_2016_04_19_milmlb_minmlb_1     L      6-0 -1.610 2.499     B  Ball
7     50 gid_2016_04_19_milmlb_minmlb_1     L      6-0 -1.177 1.543     B  Ball
8     50 gid_2016_04_19_milmlb_minmlb_1     L      6-0 -1.072 1.091     B  Ball
9     50 gid_2016_04_19_milmlb_minmlb_1     L      6-0 -0.987 3.506     B  Ball
10    34 gid_2016_04_19_milmlb_minmlb_1     L     5-10  1.962 2.302     B  Ball
```

Why is this?

Comment: could you `dput` that data?

Comment: Done. Sorry for the formatting.

Comment: It is an S4 object and the dput is not working.

Comment: Maybe put the filter into SQLite? The problem makes me think of arrange attempts on grouped data frames though.

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem a little. See above.

Comment: try `des == "Ball" | des == "Called Strike"` (single `|`) or `des %in% c("Ball","Called Strike")`

Comment: The single pipe doesn't work, but the %in% command does. I was actually trying the single pipe originally, and changed it to double out of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems dplyr's filter doesn't put parentheses around the logic arguments.

So my command

`filter(pitches, stand == "L", des == "Ball" | des == "Called Strike")`

becomes

`stand == "L" AND des == "Ball" OR des == "Called Strike"`

The correct command would be

`filter(pitches, stand == "L", (des == "Ball" | des == "Called Strike"))`